# How to configure PEAR ENV windows?

Tags: windows-7, phpunit, pear

the file .reg generate when finish the pear installation was addedd and when i try pear command i get this message:

´PHP_PEAR_PHP_BIN is not set correctly.
Please fix it using your environment variable or modify
the default value in pear.bat
The current value is:
.\php.exe´

i'm traying to install PHPUnit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the environment variable in

```
Control center 
  extended system settings
    extended
      environment variables
```

alternatively, set it directly in `pear.bat` - but that change will vanish after the next update.

Comment: i get the error. the PHP_PEAR_PHP_BIN is .\php.exe and change to MY_PHP_BIN_DIR\php.exe andworks fine